# Common methods for doing select with computation by need?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I would like to be able to add columns to a table with cells who's values are computed by need at 'querytime' when (possibly) selecting over them.

Are there some established ways of doing this?

EDIT: Okay I can do without the 'add columns'. What I want is to make a select query which searches some (if they exist) rows with all needed values computed (some function) and also fills in some of the rows which does not have all needed values computed. So each query would do it's part in extending the data a bit.
(Some columns would start out as null values or similar)

I guess I'll do the extending part first and the query after

Answer (score 0):

You use select expression, especially if you don't plan to store the calculation results, or they are dependant on more than one table. An example, as simple as it could be:

```
SELECT id, (id+1) as next_id FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of database are you asking for? If it is SQL Server then you can use the computed columns by using the AS syntax.
Eg:

```
create table Test
(
Id int identity(1,1),
col1 varchar(2) default 'NO',
col2 as col1 + ' - Why?'
)
go

insert into Test
default values
go

select * from Test

drop table Test
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL world it's usually expensive to add a column to an existing table so I'd advise against it. Maybe you can manage with something like [this](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/arithmetic-operations.php):

```
SELECT OrderID, 
       ProductID, 
       UnitPrice*Quantity AS "Regular Price", 
       UnitPrice*Quantity-UnitPrice*Quantity*Discount AS "Price After Discount"
FROM order_details;
```

If you really insist on adding a new column, you could go for something like (not tested):

```
ALTER TABLE order_details ADD column_name datatype
UPDATE order_details SET column_name = UnitPrice+1
```

You basically `ALTER TABLE` to add the new column, then perform an `UPDATE` operation on all the table to set the value of the newly added column.